# How do I add up the contents of the ages after cutting them out of the file in bash?

Tags: bash, math, line, counter, addition

I have gotten the following code to do everything I need it to, but am stumped on how to add up the ages after cutting them from the file. I am thinking I am missing something simple, but keep getting the output of each line being added by the last. Thanks for any help!!

```
#!/bin/bash

wget --user="user" --password= ftp://"address"/pub/personfile.txt > log2.out 2>&1

filename = 'personfile.txt'
n=1
while read line; do
echo "$n $line"
n=$((n+1))
done < $filename

total=0;
age=0;

filename='personfile.txt'
n=1
while read line; do
age=$(echo $line | cut -d'|' -f 3)
total=$(($total+$age))
echo="$total"
done < $filename
```

The output is supposed to be sum of all ages, it does this but adds it line by line instead of all together on one line.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: There are no *spaces* around `=` allowed in bash (e.g `filename = 'personfile.txt'`) doesn't work. Past your script into [ShellCheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and address all issues. It is a great tool. If still stuck afterwords, post the code and errors.

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to just be trying to understand the addition in bash ...

`((total=$total+$age))` should work as should (optional variable dereferencing) `((total+=age))`.

From [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/loops1.html#EX26).